# Setting Ledger Dimension(offset Account) in Movement Journal through X++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am developing a small customization in AX 2012, which will enable user to import Item Movement Journal Lines from Excel, in item movement journal we have to set `OffsetAccount` for every line, this is creating problem for me, I want to read the offset account from excel and set it for the line(in my case it is "110110 Bank Account USD"), I noticed that in `InventJournalTrans` table the field (`LedgerDimension`) is populated with a `recId`, but when I try to read this rec ID from excel and set it for `InventJournalTrans`, it tells me that this field does not exists.

My ultimate goal is to set the one single offset account for all lines, I can put it in excel or if anyone can show me how to display a segmented entry control for this purpose.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [Excel add-in](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/ax2012exceldataimport/default.aspx)?

It handles surrogate keys automatically (if the table is properly defined). RecId should never be read from Excel!

Regarding journal imports, see [this link](http://ax2012exceldataimport.blogspot.dk/).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a method in my class which will take account no (read from excel) and get its recid from table DimensionAttributeValueCombination table then I save this recId for LedgerDimension, here is my code:

```
public RecId getDimensionRecID(str _DisVal) 
{    
    DimensionAttributeValueCombination davc;
    RecId rrr;
    Name disValue;
    disValue = _DisVal;    
    select firstOnly * from davc where davc.DisplayValue == disValue;
    rrr = davc.RecId;
    return rrr; 
}
```